# How do I choose the Language for 70-536 Microsoft Exam

Tags: .net

I went today to schedule the 70-536 Framework Foundations Exam, I thought I could choose the language when registering for it, but I saw there is only one option. I guess I will have to choose the language if C# or VB.NET when taking it on one of the first screens??

I hope so, its already scheduled, and if it is in VB im screwed!...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a direct programming question, but a question about taking a certification test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can choose between VB.net and C#.net

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between VB.NET, C# and Managed C++ for the 70-536 exam.

Answer (score 0):

Don't those exams cover .NET specifics, not language specifics?

Comment: Yes, but they show code examples in the language of your choosing.